# Get or set accessor expected

Tags: c#

I have decided to make system in my code (in c#), because it was getting larger and larger (I was not expecting this when starting). So I am creating new classes with various methods and than I am calling them in my Form class. I have for example class to connect do DB and it works well. Now I want to make class with method to load a xls file. I just copied the working code from my Form class to my new class and I am getting error:

```
A get or set accessor expected
```

Here is my code:

```
class LoadReflexTime
{
    public string[,] reflexTime{
    // LOAD XLS to ARRAY
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(cesta);   // HERE IS THE ERROR
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        reflexTime = new string[rowCount, colCount];
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                string str = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Text;
                reflexTime[i - 1, j - 1] = str;
            }

            int percent = ((100 * i) / rowCount);

            this.percenta.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => percenta.Text = percent.ToString()+"%"));
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Súbor načítaný");

    }
```

This error is occuring on the line as zou can see above. Exactly here: "Excel." 
Thank you for advices.

Comment: Missing `()` in your function declaration after `reflexTime`.

Comment: Oh, I am soo blind. Thank you :)

Comment: @TimCastelijns Why didn't you post an answer? You deserved it.

Comment: @Anar I'm no C# expert. I wasn't sure the missing brackets were the source of the problem but I knew they had to be there so I figured I'd post it as comment

Comment: @TimCastelijns You can always delete your answer. Good luck.

Comment: @Anar I know but I'd rather be confident about my answer than taking a guess and hope I was right

Comment: @TimCastelijns I agree with you on that completely. I meant if you are sure for 99%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by 
[tim-castelijns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1843331/tim-castelijns)

```
class LoadReflexTime
{    
   public string[,] reflexTime(){

    //YOUR CODE

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should explicitly state what changes you made and why

Comment: Ok, I was blind and did not see it. Thx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in  function deceleration:

```
public string[,] reflexTime{
```

change it to

```
public string[,] reflexTime(){
                          ^^^^^
```

If you leave off the parenthesis it assumes you are creating a property, and you can only have a get or set within the property. The paranthesis at the end tell the compiler that this is a function decleration.